# How to make table view dynamically in jquery on load

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am beginner in jquery mobile .I just want to make table view dynamically in jquery mobile .?

i found lot of example but all are static .I want make table view using (ul ,li)or (tr td) in jquery mobile.

As shown in figure with black circle i need this type of table view which is create dyanically.

sorry due to problem i am not able to attached image.

i used this code but not able to display table .here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css">


  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>

  <!-- Extra Codiqa features -->


</head>
<style>

  .ui-page {
  background : transparent url(img/Background-Screen.png) 0 0 no-repeat fixed !important;
  background-size : cover;
}

</style>


<body>



    <!--page one My Cases Screen------------->
  <div data-role="page" id="Home">
   <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
  <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 20px;">My Cases</h1>
  <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b">Setting</a>
 <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog">Add</a>
 <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog">Edit</a>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    <p> Window content </p>  

  </div>   


  </div>






</body>


 <script >

 $(document).ready(function () {
 // $('.ui-loader').remove();
  $.mobile.loading('hide');

    var html = "";

html += "<div class=ui-grid-b>";

html +=   "<div class=ui-block-a>Element 1.1</div>";

html +=   "<div class=ui-block-b>Element 1.2</div>";

html +=   "<div class=ui-block-c>Element 1.3</div>";

html +=   "<div class=ui-block-a>Element 2.1</div>";

html +=   "<div class=ui-block-b>Element 2.2</div>";

html +=   "<div class=ui-block-c>Element 2.3</div>";

html += "</div>";

$("#home div:jqmData(role=content)").append (html);
});


</script>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? AJAX?

Comment: Yes, how do you want to create dynamically?

Comment: No .Just create simple table while launching the application.(use defulat value "1 2 3 4 5 6")

Comment: I think i have to call one function onload where i will create a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will guide you in the direction. Here's a demo at <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/xFaQ7/)</kbd>

I've got this array :

```
[
 {
    "colorName": "red",
    "hexValue": "#f00"
 },
 {
    "colorName": "green",
    "hexValue": "#0f0"
 },
 .. so on
]
```

Which I'm converting to a table with `data-role="table"` which is responsive.

For more info, look at the <kbd>[Docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/table-reflow/)</kbd> at jQuery Mobile.

Seriously, this is just normal jQuery `append()` etc. You could find this anywhere on the internet :)

Updated demo : <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/7bym8/7/</kbd>

Comment: I make simple table and append the data but problem is scrolling i need only table is scroll not header ? http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/7bym8/

Comment: @user2484319 add a `data-position="fixed"` to your header tag. Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/7bym8/1/

Comment: and how to add click event of each row i mean i have to define id on each row .if i click any row it show alert of id.

Comment: could u make a fiddle for this? or must i use the same fiddle?

Comment: One more question i need to check in which button i click (plus ,Edit,setting).How to know using only one function.? or i will make individual ids?

Comment: Thanks ..!! when  i insert class='row' id='" + i + "' in my row it will not work due to some syntax error.But upper button works .Thanks.here is my upgrade fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/7bym8/5/

Comment: updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/7bym8/6/

the problem was the double quotes :)

Comment: I don't have credential to upvote because i am new in stackoverflow

Comment: hello when i check my code on Ipad my whole page is scrolling but when i check on browser header is fixed and table is scrolling why ?

Comment: There is problem when i check on Ipad whole page is scrolling with header .I need to scroll only table (height = ipad height-header height) .here is my code.http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/Q9QmF/

Comment: I solved the Ipad issue but there is one more issue when i click the row of listview the header is hide .but when i click again on row it show why ? here is my fiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/7bym8/8/

Comment: This bug will come when you scroll the list after that you click the list then header is hide .

Comment: you mean the header moves up and down? thats default behaviour! You dont want the header to hide? Ever?